# Paperclip not deleting images from S3 on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Paperclip with AWS in my rails app. I have a model that holds the image:

```
class PaperclipFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :parse_image

  belongs_to :attachment

  attr_accessor :base64_attachment

  has_attached_file :image, preserve_files: false
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true 
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image

  private
    def parse_image
      return unless base64_attachment
      image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(base64_attachment) 
      image.original_filename = "img_#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.jpg" 
    end
end
```

Basically I can pass an image in base64 and it processes and stores it correctly on S3. The issue is when I do .destroy

```
p = PaperclipFile.first
p.destroy
```

After that the record is gone from the DB but the file is not destroyed from the bucket. I don't get any errors so it doesn't look like it's trying at all.

The output is:

```
2.4.0 :005 > PaperclipFile.first.destroy
  PaperclipFile Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "paperclip_files".* FROM "paperclip_files" ORDER BY "paperclip_files"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "paperclip_files" WHERE "paperclip_files"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]
   (4.1ms)  COMMIT
 => #<PaperclipFile id: 2, attachment_id: 2, created_at: "2017-04-03 04:02:11", updated_at: "2017-04-03 04:02:11", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :006 >
```

For the record I use Ruby 2.4, Rails 5.0.2 and as for the gems they look like this:

```
# Attachments
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you have written.

If you want to remove the image from S3 as well just make the following changes-

```
p = PaperclipFile.first
p.destroy # Removes the attachment from DB
p.clear # Deletes the attachment from S3
p.save # To save the model.
```

Comment: clear is not a function of p. Maybe you meant p.image.clear / p.image.destroy? I've also tried those without any luck

Comment: just try saving the object after you do p.image.destroy / p.image.clear

Answer (score 0):

Default preserve_files set to false. Try removing option as follow.

```
has_attached_file :image
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I've tried both with nothing and preserve_files: false with the same effect

Comment: Lets try one more way.

```p.image = nil
p.save
p.destroy```

Comment: I tried that but it did't help. Turns out it has to do with using paranoia. I removed paranoia from everywhere and it works. I have to wire it up correctly but at least I know that .destroy does delete the image now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had no issues with destroy, but I used `delete_all`, which does not triggers the callbacks, and had the same effect you have seen.

Another possible cause could have been missing permits for deleting files. 
Check the deletion directly over the ruby s3 sdk.